# What kind of word is "spite"?

Tags: language-evolution

I mostly read it in older works. Can I treat it like a regular word, and what would spito, spita, spiti etc mean?

Answer (score 8):

The definition of *spiti* in the *Plena Ilustrita Vortaro* is

> *Montri al iu, ke oni plezuras, kontraŭstarante al lia/ŝia volo, aŭ ke oni estas preta batali*
>
> To show another person that one takes pleasure in opposing their will, or that one is ready to fight

*Spite* on its own means something between "defiantly" and "spitefully". *Spite de* means "in spite of" when you want to imply that literal defiance is involved, or at very least a certain amount of cosmic irony, in contrast to *malgraŭ* which just means "despite" in its normal usage as a dead metaphor. *Spite ke* means "in spite of the fact that" and pairs with *malgraŭ ke*.